# Auto locking a sharepoint document library at a specific time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

A user has asked me if it would be possible to lock a document library at a specific time and possible on a schedule.

The puropse is to ask members of the site to submit a report by 4pm on a Friday, but at 4:01pm the library goes into read only mode.

If they haven't submitted the report, then there's trouble.

I've seen that you can acheive this via IRM, but that requires a fair bit of effort to setup, and is site wide.

Does anyone have any ideas how this might be acheived using just SharePoint 2013 out of the box?

Comment: I think you could use a SPD workflow to modify permissions at a specific time

Comment: This could help: http://spcycle.blogspot.de/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on-prem,

On your SP server, start a Task-Scheduled Powershell script which sets the Item Level Security.

**Note: The UI only exposes this for Lists, but with Code you can set this for Libraries as well!**

[image]

**with PowerShell**:

```
$spList.ReadSecurity=2 # 1=read all items, 2=read items created by user
$spList.WriteSecurity=4 # 1=Create and edit All, 2=Create and edit Own items, 4=None
```